# Cut strings (UTF-8) (PHP)

Tags: php

How to cut string in UTF 8.

I have searched from web this function:

```
function cutString($str, $lenght = 100, $end = '&nbsp;&hellip;', $charset = 'UTF-8', $token = '~') {
    $str = strip_tags($str);
    if (mb_strlen($str, $charset) >= $lenght) {
        $wrap = wordwrap($str, $lenght, $token);
        $str_cut = mb_substr($wrap, 0, mb_strpos($wrap, $token, 0, $charset), $charset);   
        return $str_cut .= $end;
    } else {
        return $str;
    }
}
```

But result of this function isn't too good. Because if we set to cut 200 letters, it will return about 110, but I need about 200.

Comment: *Minor side note:* you spelled **length** wrong :)

Comment: As for your question, are you saying you want to supply less than 200 characters and the function should return **exactly** 200 characters? Because I don't understand where the problem is. The function does exactly what you're telling it to do. As far as I can see it's working correctly.

Answer (score -1):

I have just tested it and it works fine. If you run it with

```
echo cutString($mystring, 200);
```

It returns 201 characters from the string I gave it.

Answer (score -1):

i think wordwrap() function does wrong in this case
cut the string manually. i use a function like this (just add 'mb_' and $charset to the string functions):

```
function str_cut_end_by_word($s, $max_len, $trailer = "...")
{
  if (strlen($s) <= $max_len)
    return $s;

  $s = trim($s);
  $s = substr($s, 0, $max_len);

  for ($i = strlen($s) - 1; $i >= 0; $i--)
  {
    if (in_array($s{$i}, array(" ", "\t", "\r", "\n")))
    {
      return rtrim(substr($s, 0, $i)).$trailer;
    }
  }

  return $s;
}
```